# Cmake generator expressions with whitesace strings

Tags: cmake

I have the following command that I would like to only run when the build configuration is in "Debug". I am targeting windows 10/11

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Game POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND robocopy /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources $<CONFIG>/Resources>
)
```

In order to do achieve this I have decided to use generator expressions on the COMMAND tag, so that if the build mode is not debug, then a blank expression will be added instead:

```
COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:robocopy /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources Debug/Resources>
```

However this always fails to expand the outer expression resulting in :

```
COMMAND $<1:robocopy /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources Debug/Resources>
```

I suspect it had something to do with white space within the robocopy command and so wrapped it with ""

```
COMMAND $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"robocopy /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources Debug/Resources">
```

However this expands into:

```
"\"robocopy \E \MT:16 \NS \NC \NP \NFL \NDL \R:3 \W:0 ..\Resources Debug\Resources\""
```

Resulting in the error `'"\"robocopy is not a recognized command.` 
Can anyone please help me with my problem?

Comment: The paths `../Resources` and `$<CONFIG>/Resources` are underspecified... you should use absolute paths computed from `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I am writing from memory. This might work

```
COMMAND "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"robocopy;/E;/MT:16;/NS;/NC;/NP;/NFL;/NDL;/R:3;/W:0;../Resources;Debug/Resources>"
```

It passes the list that should dump the space separated items.

Comment: It expands to the following ```$"<1:\"robocopy" /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources Debug/Resources">```

Comment: This is very nearly correct... the quotes should wrap the whole genex and both `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` and `VERBATIM` need to be set.

Comment: @AlexReinking Is my edited answer correct now? If yes, OP's `COMMAND "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:robocopy /E /MT:16 /NS /NC /NP /NFL /NDL /R:3 /W:0 ../Resources Debug/Resources>"` will also be correct?